# iptables rules being added all on their own on Centos 7 (Azure)?

Tags: centos, iptables, azure, centos7

We are trying to run a PCI scan on our internal network. For some reason, the machines are blocking the scanner automatically when the scan is running by adding its IP to the iptables.

We don't have fail2ban installed, and the firewalld service is stopped. And yet, the rules keep being added! What could be the reason for that?

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  10.2.9.4             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  10.2.9.4             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Edit: This is the audit log when the ban happens:

```
==> /var/log/audit/audit.log <==
type=AVC msg=audit(1576075680.436:1186): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=3159 comm="iptables" name="xtables.lock" dev="tmpfs" ino=24193 scontext=system_u:system_r:iptables_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1576075680.436:1186): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=4130a4 a1=40 a2=180 a3=7ffdfc25d120 items=0 ppid=3142 pid=3159 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=985 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=985 sgid=985 fsgid=985 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/usr/sbin/xtables-multi" subj=system_u:system_r:iptables_t:s0 key=(null)
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1576075680.436:1186): proctitle=2F7362696E2F69707461626C6573002D4900494E505554002D730031302E322E392E34002D6A0044524F50
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1576075680.437:1187): table=filter family=2 entries=4
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1576075680.437:1187): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=4 a1=0 a2=40 a3=10cbd80 items=0 ppid=3142 pid=3159 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=985 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=985 sgid=985 fsgid=985 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/usr/sbin/xtables-multi" subj=system_u:system_r:iptables_t:s0 key=(null)
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1576075680.437:1187): proctitle=2F7362696E2F69707461626C6573002D4900494E505554002D730031302E322E392E34002D6A0044524F50
type=AVC msg=audit(1576075680.438:1188): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=3160 comm="iptables" name="xtables.lock" dev="tmpfs" ino=24193 scontext=system_u:system_r:iptables_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_run_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1576075680.438:1188): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=4130a4 a1=40 a2=180 a3=7ffcdf8bd760 items=0 ppid=3142 pid=3160 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=985 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=985 sgid=985 fsgid=985 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/usr/sbin/xtables-multi" subj=system_u:system_r:iptables_t:s0 key=(null)
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1576075680.438:1188): proctitle=2F7362696E2F69707461626C6573002D4900464F5257415244002D730031302E322E392E34002D6A0044524F50
type=NETFILTER_CFG msg=audit(1576075680.439:1189): table=filter family=2 entries=5
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1576075680.439:1189): arch=c000003e syscall=54 success=yes exit=0 a0=4 a1=0 a2=40 a3=effef0 items=0 ppid=3142 pid=3160 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=985 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=985 sgid=985 fsgid=985 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="iptables" exe="/usr/sbin/xtables-multi" subj=system_u:system_r:iptables_t:s0 key=(null)
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1576075680.439:1189): proctitle=2F7362696E2F69707461626C6573002D4900464F5257415244002D730031302E322E392E34002D6A0044524F50
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1576075680.605:1190): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=omid comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1576075680.652:1191): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=omid comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1576075681.149:1192): pid=3232 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_access,pam_unix,pam_localuser acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1576075681.150:1193): pid=3232 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_fprintd acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=LOGIN msg=audit(1576075681.150:1194): pid=3232 uid=0 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 old-auid=4294967295 auid=0 tty=(none) old-ses=4294967295 ses=2 res=1
type=USER_START msg=audit(1576075681.163:1195): pid=3232 uid=0 auid=0 ses=2 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_loginuid,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=CRED_REFR msg=audit(1576075681.164:1196): pid=3232 uid=0 auid=0 ses=2 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_fprintd acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1576075681.209:1197): pid=3232 uid=0 auid=0 ses=2 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_env,pam_fprintd acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
type=USER_END msg=audit(1576075681.213:1198): pid=3232 uid=0 auid=0 ses=2 subj=system_u:system_r:crond_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_loginuid,pam_keyinit,pam_limits,pam_systemd acct="root" exe="/usr/sbin/crond" hostname=? addr=? terminal=cron res=success'
```

Comment: looks like a `selinux` issue

Comment: I don't think it looks like an selinux issue at all: selinux is happy to prevent a change, but it does not by itself generate iptables rules. There is apparently something else running on your systems that is performing a function similar to fail2ban. The audit logs simply show that something is modifying the filter table (which we already knew).

Comment: It seems like it's the PAM module that's been configured to block bruteforce SSH. Any idea how to disable it temporarily?